# Simple jQuery / javascript method to escape special characters in string for regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm performing a regular expression using the match() method on a string that comes from the user and could contain anything, including $^'s etc.. so I need to escape those characters before this happens.

Is there a common function in jQuery to do this, a well known javascript function or am I going to have to do it manually (with the chance I might miss something?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a function [here](http://blog.simonwillison.net/post/57956816139/escape):

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Comment: as far as I can see, it's the same replacement as in jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex, however this function is not official and can therefor be removed at any time without further notice

Comment: Used here as well: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js (search for escapeRegex)