# Jquery search and replace function

Tags: jquery

> var ara = 'facebook.com';

```
 $( "div:contains('"+ara+"')" ).each(function(){
     var ekle  = ' aaaaaaa >| ';
        veri = $(this).html();
        islenmis = veri.split(ara);

        if(islenmis[0]=='http://www.'||islenmis[0]=='https://www.'||islenmis[0]=='http://'||islenmis[0]=='https://'||islenmis[0]=='http://'||islenmis[0]=='http://'+regex(.*)){
         $(this).addClass('newClass');
        } 
     })
```

how can i find deteced from can be regex how i ll do?

```
<span>https://tr-tr.facebook.com</span>
<span>http://en-en.facebook.com</span>
<span>http://anysite.com/facebook.com</span>(no want find this result)
<span>https://www.facebook.com</span>
```

Comment: When you iterate each element, use .html() to get the text. Then just test the text to see if it matches your regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, but in this case you'll have to escape the dot in the name as it's a special character in a regex (actually it'll still mostly work without that, but it's best to do it rather than get caught with the weird case once).

The simplest is an expression to match the '//', then match anything that's not a '/' (`[^/]*`), followed by the target string, like this:

```
re = new RegExp("//[^/]*facebook\.com");
```

We should probably match the starting 'http' / 'https' just in case, I'm going to assume it's always at the start of the line, so add in a match for the line start (`^`), then `http`, then zero or one s chars (`s?`), then the colon.

If you want to escape the incoming string (so you can specific the site in a variable) try this solution here: [Simple jQuery / javascript method to escape special characters in string for regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306095/simple-jquery-javascript-method-to-escape-special-characters-in-string-for-reg)

A solution, hardcoded for facebook.com would look like:

```
$( "span:contains('facebook.com')" ).each(function(){

    re = new RegExp("^https?://[^/]*facebook\.com");

    if(re.test($(this).html())) {
        // Matched, do something ...
        console.log("MATCH: ",$(this));
    } else { 
        // Not matched, do something else (maybe) ... 
        console.log("NOMATCH: ", $(this));
    }

});
```